# How do I declare a function that returns a pointer to a function that returns a function pointer without using a typedef in C?

Tags: c, return-value, function-pointers, return-type

I was wondering how I write a function which returns a pointer to a function which returns a function pointer, without a typedef. For instance a function which returns a function pointer can be define as:

```
type (*f_name(..))(..){..}
```

So this returns a pointer to a function that returns a 'type', now how do you declare the function if the 'type' is a function pointer. But as my supervisor does not want typedefs used I can't use them.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Just replace `type` with an unnamed function pointer.

Comment: Your supervisor does not want typedefs? What a strange idea...
It is unclear what you want. Do you simply want a function that returns a function pointer, or do you want it to recursively be function-pointer-returning functions?
What have you tried?

Comment: Do it with ``typedef`` first, then resolve the ``typedef``s manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For questions like this there is a nifty utility called `cdecl` (http://cdecl.org/) which translates between english and C declarations.

For instance

```
cdecl> declare f as function (int) returning pointer to function (char) returning pointer to function (void) returning long
```

gives the answer

```
long (*(*f(int ))(char ))(void )
```

and, in the other direction,

```
cdecl> explain int (*(*g(float))(double, double))(char)
```

gives

> declare g as function (float) returning pointer to function (double,
>   double) returning pointer to function (char) returning int

Comment: Yup, just added the URL. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Thanks, this utility is nice and the given answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

First we write a function taking an int and returning a float.

```
float First( int f )
{
    return ( float )f ;
}
```

Then we write a function taking nothing and returning a pointer to a function taking an int and returning a float.
 This pointer is the same type as `First`.

```
float ( *Second( void ) )( int ) 
{
    float (*f)( int ) = First ;

return f ;
}
```

Finally we write a function taking a char and returning a pointer to a function taking nothing and returning a pointer to a function taking an int and returning a float.  This pointer is the same type as `Second`.

```
float ( *( *Third( char c ) )( void ) )( int )
{
    ( void )c ;
    float ( *(*s)( void ) )( int ) = Second ;

return s ;
}
```

If you place the prototypes along one another, the weird syntax starts to make sense:

```
float       First                    ( int ) ;
float (    *Second         ( void ) )( int ) ;
float ( *( *Third( char ) )( void ) )( int ) ;
```

The only difference to returning an non-function pointer is that function pointers parameters go at the end of the declaration, and the brackets:

```
         type*  Name( void ) ; 
function_type (*Name( void ) )( int ) ;
```